# Haskell get error when list parameter has more than one element

Tags: list, haskell, parameters

I just got into Haskell, and I'm trying to make a function that given a list of numbers will return a list of all the negative numbers in it.
So I did this

```
negative:: [Int] -> [Int]

negative [x] = [z | z <- [x], x < 0]
```

When I try it with only one element in the list it works as it should

negative [-1] returns [-1]

negative [1] returns []

However when I add more numbers like for example
negative [0,-1] I get the following error:

Program error: pattern match failure: negative [Num_fromInt instNum_v30 0,Num_fromInt instNum_v30 -1]

I tried typing the numbers with spaces and without spaces between but the result is the same. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my code, but since I'm still getting used to Haskell I'm having a hard time finding it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This error appears quite frequently on SO. I wonder if there's some course/tutorial somewhere that prods beginners in using `[x]` as a notation for an arbitrary list, instead of a singleton list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the `[x]` in the left-hand side of the expression with `x`, and change the expression `x < 0` to `z < 0` (Remember, we are filtering out individual elements, not the container itself).

Here is how I would do it:

```
negative :: [Int] -> [Int]
negative x = [z | z <- x, z < 0]
```

**(Optional)** Here is how you could solve the same problem using higher-order functions:

```
negative :: [Int] -> [Int]
negative xs = filter (< 0) xs
```

(If you don't know what higher-order functions are, just ignore the previous example. You'll learn about them as you go along)